# How to configure JDBC for Cloud Fusion to connect MySQL installed on localhost:3306

Tags: jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to connect my local standalone MySQL with Cloud Fusion to create and test a data pipeline. I have deployed the driver successfully.
Also, I have configured the pipeline properties with correct values of jdbc string, user name and password but connectivity isn't getting established.

Connection String: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_database`

I have also tried to test the connectivity via data wrangling option but that is also not getting succeeded.

Do I need to bring both the environments under same network by setting up some VPC and tunneling?

Comment: Can we connect Data Fusion to on-prem databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your question is more related to the way how to connect some on-premise environments to GCP networking system that gathering Google cloud instances or resources throughout [VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/overview) connection model.

Admitting the fact that GCP is actually leveraging different approaches for connection methods within a [Hybrid cloud](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/overview#hybrid_cloud) concepts, I would encourage you to learn some fundamental principles of [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs) as a essential part of performing secure connection between particular *[VPN Peer Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/configuring-peer-gateway)* and [*Cloud VPN Gateway*](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview#external-vpn-gateway-definition) and further creating a VPN tunnel between parties.

I guess there is even dedicated chapter in GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip#vpc_peering_with) about Data Fusion [VPC peering](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip#create_a_peering_connection) implementation that might be helpful in your user case.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, I see that you specified `localhost` in your Connection String. `localhost` is only advertised to other services running local to your machine, and Cloud Data Fusion (running in GCP) will not be able to reach the MySQL instance (running on your machine). Hence you're seeing the connectivity issue.

I highly recommend looking at this [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56159101/12481937) that will help you setup a quick proof-of-concept.