# can't connect Cloud Data Fusion with Cloud SQL for MySQL with Private IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-data-fusion, cloud-sql-proxy

I know that there is many similar questions but I'm not able to find an answer to solve my issue.

I trying to connect Data Fusion to replicate a Cloud SQL for MySQL table. When trying to connect to the MySQL table I have the following error:

```
Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

From what I have gathered I need to:

- Create the Data Fusion Private Instance by following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip)
- Create the instance for Cloud SQL for MySQL with Private IP using the default network
- Connecting the Cloud SQL instance from a VM instance following the Connect from a VM instance tutorial I found directly from the Connect to this instance section.

Everything is under the same project.

I'm trying my best here but I'm a bit lost. If someone can guide me through this.

Is there anything more I need to do here? What IP should I use when setting up the connection to MySQL in Data Fusion?

Comment: Simon: Can you provide how you installed the cloudsql mysql driver in your cloud data fusion instance? To unblock is it possible to try out the same by connecting to a public cloudsql mysql instance for now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect Cloud Data Fusion with Cloud SQL for MySQL on Private IP you will need to deploy Cloud SQL Proxy. There is a lot of documentation around it. It seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Cloud Data Fusion to just get data from CloudSQL MySQL to GCP

There are a few existing questions/docs that have been discussed in the past

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56159101/661768
- [Can't connect Cloud Data Fusion with Google Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55880595/cant-connect-cloud-data-fusion-with-google-cloud-sql-for-postgresql)
- https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/reading-from-postgresql

If you are indeed trying to use Cloud Data Fusion's Replication feature to replicate your db tables then connecting to a private CloudSQL MySQL instance is not supported yet. Here is the corresponding OSS JIRA to follow up if you are looking for this - https://cdap.atlassian.net/browse/CDAP-17938

Comment: hum ok. This is frustrating. But when connecting on public IP the only way I found is to whitelist all IPs "0.0.0.0" . Any advice around this?

Comment: Simon: Just to confirm are you still trying to use replication? Or just connecting CDF to a public cloudsql mysql? Can you share the steps you are doing for this (like a doc) where it mentions to whitelist all IPs?

Comment: I want to use replication on a private cloudsql mysql. However out of curiosity I've created a dummy cloudsql mysql db and the connection with the replication is working when I'm whitelisting "0.0.0.0"

Comment: Hhmm I don't see that as a step here - https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/mysql-to-bigquery. Did you happen to check this documentation?

Comment: This documentation is not for cloud sql mysql... or I'm missing something?

Comment: Simon: My bad. Yes you are right. The whitelisting of 0.0.0.0 is needed for CDF & Dataproc VMs to be able to talk to CloudSQL MySQL instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231530/discussion-between-simon-breton-and-ajai).